# Proof that two norms on Banach space are equivalent

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, complete-spaces

> Let $V$ be a Banach space with respect to norms $\|\cdot\|_{1}$ and $\|\cdot\|_2$. There exists $Q>0$ such that $\forall_{v\in V} \|v\|_1\leq Q\|v\|_2$. Show that there exists $P>0$ such that $\forall_{v\in V} \|v\|_2\leq P\|v\|_1$.

I have tried proving it by contradiction, but then I would get a sequence $v_n$ such that $$ \forall_n \|v_n\|_2>n\|v_n\|_1$$ and I could not get anything from it. I guess that I need to find a Cauchy sequence that doesn't converge in order to get a contradiction. Because without assumption of completeness it's obviously false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The identity map from $(V,\|.\|_2)$ to $ (V,\|.\|_1)$  is continuous and Open Mapping Theorem tells you that the identity map from  $(V,\|.\|_1)$ to $ (V,\|.\|_2)$ is continuous. This gives the desired inequality.

Answer (score 0):

(After some discussion in the comments, this is a proof to a different result.)

**Lemma.** A necessary and sufficient condition for a linear function $u$ to be continuous between two normed spaces $\mathrm{V}$ and $\mathrm{W}$ is that there should exists a $c > 0$ such that $\| u(x) \| \leq c \|x\|$ for all $x \in \mathrm{V}.$

*Proof.* The condition is trivially sufficient, let us focus on the necessity. Then $u$ is continuous at zero and this means that the inverse image by $u$ of the unit ball in $\mathrm{W}$ contains a ball $\mathrm{B} = \mathrm{B}(0; \frac{2}{c})$ in $\mathrm{V}.$  Then, for any $x \in \mathrm{V},$ we have $\dfrac{x}{c \|x\|} \in \mathrm{B}$ and so its image is inside the unit ball of $\mathrm{W},$ implying the desired result by linearity. $\square$

**Lemma.** If two norms $\| \cdot \|_1$ and $\| \cdot \|_2$ in a given vector space engender the same topology (i.e. they furnish the vector space with the same open sets), then there exists constants $C, c > 0$ such that $c \| \cdot \|_1 \leq \| \cdot \|_2 \leq C \| \cdot \|_1.$

*Proof.* Let $\mathrm{V}$ be the given vector space endowed with the norm $\| \cdot \|_1$ and let $\mathrm{W}$ the same vector space but now endowed with $\| \cdot \|_2.$ By the previous lemma, and upon noticing the hypothesis is equivalent to stating that the identity (linear) function is continuous $\mathrm{V} \to \mathrm{W}$ and $\mathrm{W} \to \mathrm{V}$, the result follows.

**To your exercise.** It is immediate from the previous lemma, in fact, the condition of completeness can be entirely dropped (as opposed to use Banach's open function theorem). What I showed is that any two norms that engender the same topology on a given vector space must necessarily be uniformly equivalent; futhermore, the same result and proof holds for Fréchet spaces.

Comment: The question doesn't assume both norms induce the same topology.  It assumes the space is complete under each norm.  Your answer is a legitimate answer to a different question.  But there's a major difference that the first answer depends on the axiom of choice while the second answer doesn't.

Comment: In a metric space, the topology is characterized by convergence of sequences, isn't?

Comment: Ah..., I think I see the subtetly, it just assumes that it has a topology under each norm that is complete and that the identity is continuous on one direction. In that case Banach's theorem is unavoidable I think.